# React useState and useEffect nesting. Is this okay?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm playing with React hooks, and I'm trying to make a very basic clock. It's working fine and dandy, even the profiler says there are no weird rerenders going on. The part that worries me a bit is where useEffect calls updateTimeAndDate, which changes the state. I feel like it should go into a rerender loop. Why does it still work? I can't put it any better, sorry. :D

Could it also be a bit nicer? Here it is:

```
const addZero = (trunk) => (trunk >= 10 ? "" : "0") + trunk;

const [hours, setHours] = useState(addZero(0));
const [minutes, setMinutes] = useState(addZero(0));

let timeAndDate;

function updateTimeAndDate() {
  timeAndDate = new Date();

  setHours(addZero(timeAndDate.getHours()));
  setMinutes(addZero(timeAndDate.getMinutes()));
}

useEffect(() => {
  updateTimeAndDate();
});

setInterval(updateTimeAndDate, 500);
```

I put useEffect there to update the time immediately after loading the page, instead of waiting for a long long half second.

Comment: Thank you, I've just noticed and edited the question to make more sense.

Comment: Side notes. (1) Put the interval inside useEffect to clear it when the component is unmounted - https://stackoverflow.com/q/53859601/863110. (2) You don't need `addZero(0)` because you know that `0` should be `00`. (3) `useEffect` should receive an array as argument otherwise the call will fire more than you want.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple issues that you will encounter with the code you've showed:

- You will run an infinitely loop that causes your component to rapidly re-render. This is because you are calling `setInterval` on every render, and by calling `updateTimeAndDate` within `setInterval`, you are updating state, which in turns causes the component to re-render.
- You have not specified a dependency array in your `useEffect`, so it will run on every re-render, further amplifying the infinite loop problem.

A possible alternative would be to only call the `useEffect` once by specifying an empty dependency array. You can also clear the interval when your component unmounts (by specifying a return value in your `useEffect`).

Here's a codesandbox demonstrating: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-overflow-set-interval-89spq

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const addZero = trunk => (trunk >= 10 ? "" : "0") + trunk;

  const [hours, setHours] = useState(addZero(0));
  const [minutes, setMinutes] = useState(addZero(0));
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(addZero(0));

  let timeAndDate;

  function updateTimeAndDate() {
    timeAndDate = new Date();

    setHours(addZero(timeAndDate.getHours()));
    setMinutes(addZero(timeAndDate.getMinutes()));
    setSeconds(addZero(timeAndDate.getSeconds()));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(updateTimeAndDate, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  // setInterval(updateTimeAndDate, 500);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{hours}</h1>
      <h2>{minutes}</h2>
      <h3>{seconds}</h3>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions

> Is it ok?

Calling `updateTimeAndDate` (which updates the state) inside `useEffect` is ok. Nevertheless, in your current code you will face issues with interval as @RobertCooper mentioned.

However, I disagree with Robert on one thing. And it is that you will fall in the infinite loop. This leads us to your second question:

> I feel like it should go into a rerender loop. Why does it still work?

Your current code does not fall into infinite loop due to the way React handles effects.

According to the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html):

> If you update a State Hook to the same value as the current state, React will bail out without rendering the children or firing effects.

Therefore, as you update the state with same hour and same minute React does not fire your effect. Hence, there is no infinite loop in this particular case.

Comment: Thanks you for the explanation!